# Manage a lot of addon_pref settings efficiently?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

i try to save a lot of user stored data inside of the addon pref and i would like to have something like that.

```
class myaddonpref(AddonPreferences):
    bl_idname = __name__
    addon_prefs = context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences

    myEnumpref._01 = EnumProperty(name='Categories',description='test',items =[('Keymap','Keymap','','MOUSE_MMB',1),('Custom Slots','Custom Slots','','COLLAPSEMENU',2),('Auto Slots','Auto Slots','','COLLAPSEMENU',3),('Notes','Notes','','FILE_TEXT',4),],default='Custom Slots')
    myboolpref._01 = BoolProperty(name="Use Custom slot 01 for scattering",subtype='NONE',default=True)

    myEnumpref._02 = EnumProperty(name='Categories',description='test',items =[('Keymap','Keymap','','MOUSE_MMB',1),('Custom Slots','Custom Slots','','COLLAPSEMENU',2),('Auto Slots','Auto Slots','','COLLAPSEMENU',3),('Notes','Notes','','FILE_TEXT',4),],default='Custom Slots')
    myboolpref._02 = BoolProperty(name="Use Custom slot 01 for scattering",subtype='NONE',default=True)

    myEnumpref._03 = EnumProperty(name='Categories',description='test',items =[('Keymap','Keymap','','MOUSE_MMB',1),('Custom Slots','Custom Slots','','COLLAPSEMENU',2),('Auto Slots','Auto Slots','','COLLAPSEMENU',3),('Notes','Notes','','FILE_TEXT',4),],default='Custom Slots')
    myboolpref._03 = BoolProperty(name="Use Custom slot 01 for scattering",subtype='NONE',default=True)
```

This kind of keywords (with dots) don't work for addon prefs. it could be really really really useful for me later when creating **def** of whole operators to easely influence parameters to the operator.

for example like this:

```
def myautomaticoperator(_XX):
    if addon_prefs.myboolpref._XX == True:
        if addon_prefs.myEnumpref._XX ==False:
            print('hello world')

myautomaticoperator(_01)
myautomaticoperator(_02)
myautomaticoperator(_03)
```

This could really really really boost my workflow. How am is supposed to make this work ? could someone show me ?

**it could be even better to use an int like this. myboolpref.02**

i also tried to do that with list.

```
    name = [StringProperty(name="Custom slot name",subtype='NONE',default="Custom01"),
                    StringProperty(name="Custom slot name",subtype='NONE',default="Custom02")]

... ...

        col.prop(self,"name[0]")
        col.prop(self,"name[1]")
```

but it didn't work. name[x] was not recognized.

i also tried `class xxx(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):` but how to let the user save his property like he does in the addon_pref class ?

i'm so confused, i just want to find a better organisation system !